# Docker: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, docker, yii2, mariadb

Hey guys I'm trying to connect `Yii2` with `mysql` running on `mariadb`.

I'm using docker and I have these containers

`mariadb` and `php-fpm` I can connect to mysql inside `mariadb` container using this command `mysql -u root -p` with no problem.
also using `mysql workbench` i can connect to mysql also through tunneling no problem there also.

But when I ran the site eg. mysite.com/user/login, when logging in I get this error

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`
`Caused by: PDOException`

this is my `mariadb` config inside docker-compose file

```
mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadb
    working_dir: /bitnami/mariadb
    volumes:
        - ./data/mariadb:/bitnami/mariadb
    environment:
        - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
        - MARIADB_DATABASE=mydb
        - MARIADB_USER=david
        - MARIADB_PASSWORD=pass
    ports:
        - "8890:3306"
```

on my `main.php` config in `Yii2` I have this as my `dsn`
`mysql:host=ipvalueofmysite.com;port=8890;dbname=mydb`

Comment: did you try with localhost ?

Comment: no because i don't think it will work because I'm doing that on a server not in my local.

Comment: so you connect remote mysql from your local environment ? or your code and mysql both works remote ?

Comment: yes everything is remote

Comment: then you can use localhost they are in same server

Comment: you know I tried this `print_r(Yii::$app->db);exit();` the output gave me this [dsn] => mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii2advanced                   
  [username] => root
    [password] =>  update: I tried localhost still the same

Comment: can you share your config file ? also instead of localhost can you type `mariadb` should be something like this

`mysql:host=mariadb;dbname=yii2advanced [username] => root [password] => update`

Comment: It's okay now I run the yii2 init function then it produced an unexpected code i removed that then the error is gone

Answer (score 2):

In my case I found the solution [here](http://codeinitiator.com/2019/08/19/using-docker-i-get-the-error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory/)

Basically when in docker, the `db` service name becomes the hostname of the database, I needed to exchange `localhost` to `db` and the error was gone. Weird, I know. :)